# How to add a facebook like button to vb.net winform application?

Tags: vb.net, facebook

I am presently working with winforms and I would like to add facebook like button to my winforms.So at present I have downloaded facebook developer toolkit and after that I am trying to add the like button.So I would like to know how to proceed further to achieve in adding the like button.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add this for your Button_click:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myProcess As New Process()
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "a.html"
    myProcess.Start()
End Sub
```

and have the a.html file available to your process with this contents:

```
<html>
<HEAD>  
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.facebook.com/home.php">
</HEAD> 
</html>
```

redirects after 0 (content=) seconds to the new page

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply and actually I need a plugin type so that when the user clicks on the button he needs to get the authentication done and there he need to show the plugin(not the fan page) so that he can click the like button.And now I am getting the error as:Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: I have placed the image you can see what actually Ineed.

Comment: File not found: I put my files in the programs directory. Or else fully specify it. I cann't help you with the Facebook specific problem, In hoped to help you to open any known internet address from your application, using the redirect. As long as "they" don't change the structure of their website , you're safe with it.